# What technique do I use to predict number of calls based on credit score?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, credit-scoring

I'm new to stats, but have been given this project: There is a call center which calls up leads and tries to get them to buy one of our products. (These are people who came to our website and filled up an interest form for one of our products) At present, every lead is called a fixed number of times. We need to change this based on their credit scores. The output I need to give is similar to this:

```
Credit Score Range        Maximum No. of Calls
0-25                          10
25-50                         15
50-75                         20
```

and so on. Also, I need to provide them with exceptions, if any.

I have a bunch of data for every lead, including gender, age, state, city, product of interest. I have around 50k leads to work on.

How do I go about this? I am feeling scared. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have tried to Google classification, clustering etc, but it is overwhelming and I don't know where to start!

Comment: Do you have any historical data on how previous leads have behaved? If you had it, you could do reframe your problem as [lead scoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_scoring) and deduce the maximum number of calls from the rank of the lead. This would be basically a classification problem. If you don't have historical data, yes you could try some unsupervised e.g. clustering as you mention, but at the end you would need your clusters to tell how likely/unlikely it is that the lead converts/pays, and honestly I don't know how you're going to get that info. Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe the point is that you should reframe your business problem. I guess the business objective is to maximize the number of calls to customers that are going to convert? That would be lead scoring. If the objective is to maximize calls to customers that are not going to default, given that you have already a credit score, you could also define a cost/benefit analysis from business info. But in both cases you would need access to history...